# C++ const reference allows change from an expression?

Tags: c++

In the section about const references in C++ Primer 5th Edition, there is this small example block:

```
int i = 42;
const int &r1 = i; // we can bind a const int& to a plain int object
const int &r2 = 42; // ok: r1 is a reference to const
const int &r3 = r1 * 2; // ok: r3 is a reference to const
int &r4 = r * 2; // error: r4 is a plain, non const reference
```

On the fourth line, I was just curious as to how a constant reference of a constant reference is able to successfully multiply the value by 2. Doesn't a conversion happen when r1 references i, making everything a constant? Or is the expression in line 4 standalone to r3?

Comment: const reference can always bind to literals... That is why many function arguments are const reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line

```cpp
const int& r3 = r1 * 2;
```

a temporary `int` is created and copy-initialized from the initializer expression `r1 * 2`, then `r3` is bound to the temporary. This does not modify the referent of `r1` any more than evaluating `3 * 2` modifies `3`.

Comment: Note that the temporary lvalue has the same lifespan as the reference

Answer (score 0):

In

```
int& r4 = r * 2;
```

I'm not sure what r is supposed to be. Supposing you actually meant `i` (or `r3`, or any other `int`): `r * 2` (or any other expression, including just `2`) is a temporary. C++ forbids binding a temporary to a non-const reference. The reason for this is to avoid confusion -- in the very earliest days of C++, binding a temporary to a non-const reference was allowed which resulted in things like:

```
void f( int& toto )
{
    toto += 1;
}
```

If the caller passed a non-lvalue (an arbitrary expression or a literal), the change to `toto` would be thrown out as soon as the function returned. Another possibility would be a core dump, because in the case of a literal, the compiler could have put the value in read-only memory.